# css selector all elements except input type checkbox

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I apply this css class to all elements **except** input type checkbox? Here is what I have, but it is not working:

```css
.dim:not(input[type="checkbox"]) {
    -webkit-opacity: 0.25;
    -moz-opacity: 0.25;
    filter:alpha(opacity=25);
    opacity: 0.25;
}
```

And the html I applying this on:

```
<tr class="dim">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-large enforce-label" name="labels[]" maxlength="30">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-large" name="addresses[]" maxlength="255">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-small" name="ssh_usernames[]" maxlength="100">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-small enforce-ssh-port" name="ssh_ports[]" maxlength="5">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: *All* elements? Including the `td` and the other `input` elements? That's going to cause the opacity to stack multiplicatively resulting in 0.0625 opacity for the input elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All inputs in class **dim**

```
.dim input{...........}
```

All inputs but not of type checkbox

```
.dim input:not([type=checkbox]){}
```

so following css works:

```
.dim input:not([type=checkbox]){
    -webkit-opacity: 0.25;
    -moz-opacity: 0.25;
    filter:alpha(opacity=25);
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/efpL2/

Answer (score 1):

Add a space between `.dim` and `:not`, and remove the word `input`.

Without the space, your selector only matches elements with `class="dim"` that aren't checkboxes.  In this case, the only thing that this matches is the outer `<tr>` (it has `class="dim"` and isn't a checkbox), which probably isn't what your trying to do.

With the space, your selector matches *descendants* of elements with `class="dim"` that aren't checkboxes.  (You might also want to change the selector to something more specific, like `.dim > td > :not([type="checkbox"])`, if you only want it to match the form elements).

You need to remove the word `input` because `:not` only accepts a single simple selector.  You can write `:not([type="checkbox"]))` since `[type="checkbox"]` is a simple selector, but you can't write `:not(input[type="checkbox"])` because `input` and `[type="checkbox"]` are two different single selectors.

Comment: Another issue is that `:not()` accepts only one simple selector at a time. `input[type="checkbox"]` is a compound selector made of two simple selectors. The easiest solution if using `.dim > td >` would be to move the `input` selector outside of the `:not()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
input:not([type="checkbox"]) {
-webkit-opacity: 0.25;
-moz-opacity: 0.25;
filter:alpha(opacity=25);
opacity: 0.25;
}
```

or instead of declaring the .dim class in the TR, declare it in a wrapping DIV like so:

```
      <div class="dim">
        <tr >
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-large enforce-label" name="labels[]" maxlength="30">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-large" name="addresses[]" maxlength="255">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-small" name="ssh_usernames[]" maxlength="100">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-small enforce-ssh-port" name="ssh_ports[]" maxlength="5">
            </td>
        </tr>
   </div><!--end .dim-->
```

CSS:

```
.dim input:not([type="checkbox"]) {
-webkit-opacity: 0.25;
-moz-opacity: 0.25;
filter:alpha(opacity=25);
opacity: 0.25;
}
```